# How to move the legend title next to the gradient spectrum?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to rotate the title legend and then align in next to legend of the color gradient. I can rotate the title but when I tweak the hjust/vjust the position of the title does not seem to change.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg, fill = drat)) + geom_point() +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(angle = 90, vjust= 5))
```

Comment: ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg, colour = drat)) + geom_point() +theme(legend.title =element_text(angle=90))+ guides(colour = guide_legend(title = "drat", angle=90, title.position="left"))

Comment: `+ theme(legend.title = element_text(angle = 90)) + guides(colour = guide_colorbar(title = "drat", title.position="left"))` will do, but I can't unstick it from the color bar.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(disp, mpg, fill= drat)) +theme(legend.title = element_text(angle = 90, vjust= 5))+
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(title.position = "left"))
```

Comment: thanks. `vjust= 5` doesn't do anything...I was still hoping for a solution that would allow tweaking the title position (the title almost touches the colorbar, while would like to adjust the spacing)